# Define same type for multiple variables, recognition in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

```
var foo, bar;
```

For this statement and using JSDoc, how to set both variables [as a given type](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) in one line so that WebStorm recognizes it? Arbitrarily, let's take `String` and use a working example:

```
/**
 * @type {String}
 */
var foo;
/**
 * @type {String}
 */
var bar;
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are now recognized as typed `String`, but it is redundant. Some naive try to 'type' both of them were:

```
//None of the following works
/**
 * @type {String}
 */
/**
 * @type {String, String}
 */
var foo, bar;
//
var
  /**
   * @type {String}
   */
  foo,
  /**
   * @type {String}
   */
  bar;
```

But I'm not sure if it's valid JSDoc anymore, and it didn't work anyway!

Is it possible to set the type of multiple variables in one `var` statement, and if so how?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible, and is unlikely to be well-supported, since it's generally considered mediocre practice to define multiple variables in one statement and JSDoc certainly isn't set up to support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-12376](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12376) to be notified on updates.
I'd suggest using inline docs (https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/InlineDocs) as a workaround:

```
var /** String*/ foo, /**String*/ bar;
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but it doesn't trigger WebStorm auto-completion. Is it supposed to? -Woops! Never mind, just had to trim the type `/**myType*/` instead of `/** myType */`